# In Angular2, the code inside of a class definition seems like initializers, and so is constructor(), what is the difference?

Tags: angular

I saw some Angular2 code:

```
export class CoursesComponent {
    foo = "wah la";
    courses;

    constructor(courseService: CourseService) {
        this.courses = courseService.getCourses();
    }
}
```

if the code inside of a class definition `foo = ...` is initializers, and `constructor() {}` is also an initializer, why do we need both and what is the difference?

Comment: what do you mean by `initializer`? sorry don't really understood what you wanted to ask..

Comment: Not exactly. Here it's about field initializers and contructors. The linked question is about constructor and `ngOnInit()`

Comment: @PankajParkar initializer as in vanilla JavaScript constructor, `function Animal(name) { this.name = name; this.energyLevel = 100;  }`

Answer (score 1):

Field initilizers are convenient. they are short and make the code easier to read but they are quite limited. You can't access any parameters passed to the constructor and you can't access any other field from the class in the initialization expression.

```
foo = "wah la";
```

The constructor is more powerful

```
constructor(courseService: CourseService) {
    this.courses = courseService.getCourses();
}
```

You can initialize local field depending on values that are passed by the constructor and also access other local field in the expressions. You can also use `if`, `for`, ... and other controls statements that are not supported in field initializers.

There is also

```
constructor(private courseService: CourseService)
```

or

```
constructor(public courseService: CourseService)
```

which is a shorthand for

```
private /* or public */ courseService:CourseService;

constructor(courseService: CourseService) {
  this.courseService = courseService;
}
```